# How to use the MVVM RelayCommand Attribute?

Tags: c#, mvvm, attributes, winui-3, community-toolkit-mvvm

I have been trying out attributes and ran in an issue trying to use the RelayCommand attribute from the Community Toolkit.

I looked over the
[.NET Documentation on RelayCommand Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/relaycommand) and tried to implement a simple example as follows:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

namespace HelloWorld_WinUI3.ViewModels;

public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
    }

    private int _counter = 0;

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        MyString = $"Hello {_counter++}";
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _myString = "Hello"; 
}
```

This produces the error: [CS0616](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0616?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0616))  'RelayCommand' is not an attribute class

Can someone explain what is wrong with this code and how to use the [RelayCommand] attribute properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CommunityToolkit.Mvvm works with WinUI 3 and.NET7. Actually, I use it a lot, including every sample I create for StackOverflow answers.

I guess, you might be facing this known [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/67123#issuecomment-1489157031).

So, at this moment, try the v8.0 instead of v8.1.

Comment: Turns out I was using 7.1.2. Updating it to 8.0.0 or 8.1.0 fixed the issue for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using MVVM Source generators is still problematic for WinUI 3; I suggest using raw Relay command declaration:

```
public class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        IncrementCounterCommand = new RelayCommand(IncrementCounter);
    }

    private int counter;

    public int Counter
    {
        get => counter;
        private set => SetProperty(ref counter, value);
    }

    public ICommand IncrementCounterCommand { get; }

    private void IncrementCounter() => Counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the CommunityToolkit does not fully support WinUI3 or .NET 7 at this time [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/).

Running the same example on a WPF project works fine.

- [ObservableProperty] seems to work in a WinUI3 project
- [RelayCommand] does not work with WinUI3 project.